# Can I use a client component (nav bar) in the root layout of my Next.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, client, app-router

I'm using Next.js and I have a root layout file in my app router. However, i'm encountering an error in my `<Nav/>` component because it's using state to keep track of whether the mobile nav is open or not.

the error says:

> You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.

in my root `layout.js` file:

```
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Hero from './components/hero';
import Nav from './components/nav';
import "../styles/globals.css"

export default function Layout({ children }) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Nav />
      <Hero />
      <main className='bg-white'> 
          {children}
      </main>
      <Footer />    
    </html>

  )
}
```

my `<Nav/>` file:

```
"use client"
import Link from "next/link"
import { useState } from "react"


const Nav = () => {
    
    const [isOpen, setNav] = useState(false)
    const toggleNav = () => {
        setNav(!isOpen)
    }

    return (
        <div className="shadow-xl bg-gray-900">
            <div className="h-12 max-w-7xl m-auto px-12">

                {/* mobile nav */}
                {
                    isOpen 
                    ?
                    // expanded nav
                    <div className="md:hidden flex flex-col gap-10 justify-center h-screen w-screen fixed bg-gray-900 left-0">
                        <Link href="/" className="text-center font-thin text-xl" onClick={toggleNav}><span> Home </span></Link>
                        <Link href="/about" className="text-center font-thin text-xl" onClick={toggleNav}><span> About </span></Link>                    
                        <Link href="/contact" className="text-center font-thin text-xl" onClick={toggleNav}><span> Contact </span></Link>                    
                        <Link href="/admin" className="text-center font-thin text-xl" onClick={toggleNav}><span> Admin </span></Link>                    
                        <svg onClick={toggleNav} x="0px" y="0px"  className="w-8 cursor-pointer mx-auto" viewBox="0 0 122.879 122.879">
                            <g>
                                <path fill="white" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M61.44,0c33.933,0,61.439,27.507,61.439,61.439 s-27.506,61.439-61.439,61.439C27.507,122.879,0,95.372,0,61.439S27.507,0,61.44,0L61.44,0z M73.451,39.151 c2.75-2.793,7.221-2.805,9.986-0.027c2.764,2.776,2.775,7.292,0.027,10.083L71.4,61.445l12.076,12.249 c2.729,2.77,2.689,7.257-0.08,10.022c-2.773,2.765-7.23,2.758-9.955-0.013L61.446,71.54L49.428,83.728 c-2.75,2.793-7.22,2.805-9.986,0.027c-2.763-2.776-2.776-7.293-0.027-10.084L51.48,61.434L39.403,49.185 c-2.728-2.769-2.689-7.256,0.082-10.022c2.772-2.765,7.229-2.758,9.953,0.013l11.997,12.165L73.451,39.151L73.451,39.151z"/>
                            </g>
                        </svg> 
                    </div> 
                    :
                    // hamburger icon
                    <div className="md:hidden flex flex-row justify-end h-full">
                        <svg onClick={toggleNav} fill="white" className="h-8 my-auto cursor-pointer" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 122.88 103.17">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M26,0h70.87c7.15,0,13.65,2.93,18.36,7.64l0.22,0.24c4.58,4.69,7.42,11.1,7.42,18.13v51.16c0,7.15-2.93,13.65-7.64,18.36 c-4.71,4.71-11.21,7.64-18.36,7.64H26c-7.14,0-13.64-2.93-18.35-7.64H7.64C2.93,90.82,0,84.32,0,77.16V26 c0-7.13,2.92-13.63,7.64-18.35l0.02-0.03C12.38,2.92,18.87,0,26,0L26,0z M41.31,29.74h40.26c2.25,0,4.09,1.84,4.09,4.09l0,0 c0,2.25-1.84,4.09-4.09,4.09H41.31c-2.25,0-4.09-1.84-4.09-4.09l0,0C37.22,31.58,39.06,29.74,41.31,29.74L41.31,29.74L41.31,29.74z M41.31,65.25h40.26c2.25,0,4.09,1.84,4.09,4.09l0,0c0,2.25-1.84,4.09-4.09,4.09l-40.26,0c-2.25,0-4.09-1.84-4.09-4.09l0,0 C37.22,67.09,39.06,65.25,41.31,65.25L41.31,65.25L41.31,65.25z M41.31,47.5h40.26c2.25,0,4.09,1.84,4.09,4.09l0,0 c0,2.25-1.84,4.09-4.09,4.09H41.31c-2.25,0-4.09-1.84-4.09-4.09l0,0C37.22,49.34,39.06,47.5,41.31,47.5L41.31,47.5L41.31,47.5z M96.88,8.2H26c-4.9,0-9.35,2-12.57,5.22l-0.02,0.02C10.2,16.65,8.2,21.1,8.2,26v51.16c0,4.89,2.01,9.34,5.23,12.56l-0.01,0.01 c3.23,3.22,7.68,5.23,12.57,5.23h70.87c4.88,0,9.33-2.01,12.56-5.24c3.23-3.23,5.24-7.68,5.24-12.56V26c0-4.8-1.93-9.17-5.04-12.39 l-0.19-0.18C106.21,10.21,101.77,8.2,96.88,8.2L96.88,8.2z"/>
                            </g>
                        </svg>                        
                    </div>
                }


                {/* desktop */}
                <div className="hidden md:flex gap-10 h-full flex-row justify-end">
                    <Link href="/" className="flex flex-col justify-center"><span> Home </span></Link>
                    <Link href="/about" className="flex flex-col justify-center"><span> About </span></Link>                    
                    <Link href="/contact" className="flex flex-col justify-center"><span> Contact </span></Link>
                    <Link href="/admin" className="flex flex-col justify-center"><span> Admin </span></Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Nav
```

I've tried adding "use client" to the top of my `<Nav/>` component, but it disables all of my event handlers and state in the component, rendering it useless on mobile. I'm not clear on the relationship between client and server components works, or how event handlers should work in this case.

Is there a way to get around this error while maintaining the nav's position in the root layout and also keep its interactivity?

Comment: Can you add your Nav component too?

Answer (score 0):

Add `'use client'` to your Main component

Comment: my main component being my `<Nav/>` ? my 'main' tags are just wrapping the children props so i don't see how this changes anything

Comment: can you update your question with the code of your Nav component?

Comment: updated! @X8inez

Comment: Your `Nav` component works fine on Mobile. Can you post a screenshot of what it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

you must put `use client` into top of your `<Nav/>` component. Because you need to specify that it will be client component which will be rendered on client side (in browser).

if you want to understand more about the issue, so go [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components)

Comment: i've tried this, which removes the error.. however, it takes away interactivity in my nav component

Comment: updated! @LordKnedlik